# parsing json values by name

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Could anyone point me in the right direction for parsing some JSON in Python please, I haven't been able to find a way to do it

```
data = {
    "profile": {
        "properties": [

            {
                "name": "SavedNetworkAddress",
                "type": "StrProperty",
                "value": "111.111.111.111"
            }, {
                "name": "PlayerName",
                "type": "StrProperty",
                "value": "TEST"
            }, {
                "name": "bFirstSpawned",
                "type": "BoolProperty",
                "value": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

if I use the line as below it will return the `111.111.111.111` value in the `'SavedNetworkAddress'` section, however in my source data that particular section may not be in the first position of the array

```
print(data['profile']['properties'][0]['value'])
```

I would need to use something to get the value thats in the same section as 'SavedNetworkAddress' but I cant find out a way to do it in python

I've been able to get it to work in powershell but with the size of the files then it is taking a very long time to run

Thanks!

Comment: So, what is ‘data’ in your code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

Json is analogous to dictionaries in Python. As the value to your key `properties` is a json array (it's a list of dictionaries here, you can simply iterate through the list and see if the key `name` matches to `SavedNetworkAddress`

Below is the code for the same:

```
for i in range(len(data['profile']['properties'])):
    if data['profile']['properties'][i]['name'] == "SavedNetworkAddress":
        print(data['profile']['properties'][i]['value'])
```

### Edit

There is a small error in your data, Python won't be able to recognize `true`. So please either convert `true` to string or convert it to python keyword `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually check each sub-dictionary in a loop:

```
for d in data['profile']['properties']:
    if d['name'] == 'SavedNetworkAddress':
        print(d['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this,

```
next(x['value'] for x in data['profile']['properties'] if x['name'] == 'SavedNetworkAddress')
```

You basically loop for the elements in the list and return the value of the first element that matches the name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print([print([d['value'] for d in data['profile']['properties'] if d["name"]=="SavedNetworkAddress"]))
```

You need to iterate all objects in `properties` and check your condition

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as you have a **dictionary**, another approach would be using `dict.items()` and `dict.keys()` methods consecutively such as

```py
for i in data.items():
    for k in data[i[0]].keys():
        for v in data[i[0]][k]:
            if v['name']=='SavedNetworkAddress':
                print(v['value'])
```